# getting omniauth to mock login for request specs in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, integration-testing, rspec-rails, omniauth-google-oauth2

I wrote a test to assert certain requests can only be performed by logged in users, who will be logging in using Devise & Omniauth's Google OAuth2 system. I cannot find a way to mock omniauth into returning a logged in user, picked up the example from [Omniauth Wiki page about Integration Tests support](https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth/wiki/Integration-Testing)

Here's the spec

```
  describe "allows logged in users" do
    before(:each) do
            OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
            OmniAuth.config.add_mock(:google, {:uid => '12345'})
            Rails.application.env_config["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
            Rails.application.env_config["omniauth.auth"] = OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:google]
    end

    it "new certification form" do
        get new_certification_path
        expect(response).to be_success
    end

    it "to create certification" do
        certification_attributes = FactoryGirl.attributes_for :certification 
        expect {
            post "/certifications", params: { certification: certification_attributes }
        }.to change(Certification, :count)

        expect(response).to redirect_to certification_path
    end

    end
```

Needless to say I cannot decipher much on why or where it is failing from the given error, I assume it is because the user cannot login

```
Failures:

  1) Certifications allows logged in users new certification form
     Failure/Error: expect(response).to be_success
       expected `#<ActionDispatch::TestResponse:0x007fb23b4c2990 @mon_owner=nil, @mon_count=0, @mon_mutex=#<Thread::Mu..., @method=nil, @request_method=nil, @remote_ip=nil, @original_fullpath=nil, @fullpath=nil, @ip=nil>>.success?` to return true, got false
     # ./spec/requests/certifications_spec.rb:49:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Certifications allows logged in users to create certification
     Failure/Error:
       expect {
        post "/certifications", params: { certification: certification_attributes }
       }.to change(Certification, :count)

       expected #count to have changed, but is still 0
     # ./spec/requests/certifications_spec.rb:54:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was using the wrong config

this goes into `spec/support/rails_helper`

```
  OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
  OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:google_oauth2] = OmniAuth::AuthHash.new({
      :provider => "google_oauth2",
      :uid => "123456789",
      :info => {
        :name => "Tony Stark",
        :email => "tony@stark.com"
      },
      :credentials => {
        :token => "token",
        :refresh_token => "refresh token"
      }
    }
  )
```

and then the before method

```
before(:each) do
        Rails.application.env_config["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
        Rails.application.env_config["omniauth.auth"] = OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:google_oauth2]
end
```